# Origine della frase "i [qualcosa], quelli belli"

Tags: phrase-origin, phrases

C'è un tipo di frase che viene usato spesso sui social network a mo' di didascalia di una foto:

> I regali, quelli belli
>
> Le colazioni, quelle belle

per intendere "guardate che bello questo regalo" o "guardate che bella questa colazione", a volte con accezione ironica.

Direi che è molto costante nella forma: «***i/gli/le [qualcosa], quelli/e belli/e***». A volte può capitare che l'aggettivo non sia "bello" ma un altro ("gli scherzi, quelli simpatici"), ma "bello" è di gran lunga il più frequente. La frase di solito costituisce da sola l'intera didascalia, eventualmente insieme a hashtag e menzioni.

### Domanda

Mi chiedevo se fosse un'espressione emersa casualmente dal nulla ed affermatasi grazie all'uso, o se nasce da qualche fonte celebre (libro, canzone, spot pubblicitario, post di celebrità), e in tal caso se sapreste aiutarmi ad individuarla.

---

### Esempi

Alcuni esempi (da pagine pubbliche)

[da Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/commentimemorabili2.0/photos/le-sorprese-quelle-belle/2051855468422994/), febbraio 2018:

[image: commenti memorabili dice "Le sorprese, quelle belle"]

[da Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BNmeHipBvSq/?hl=en), dicembre 2016:

[image: lasabrigamer dice "I regali, quelli belli!!"]

[da Twitter](https://twitter.com/sirdistruggere/status/921090589269032960?lang=en), ottobre 2017:

[image: il signor distruggere dice "I regali, quelli belli."]

[da Tripadvisor](https://it.tripadvisor.ch/ShowUserReviews-g608901-d6661916-r568742020-Il_Vecchio_e_il_Mare-Trani_Province_of_Barletta_Andria_Trani_Puglia.html), marzo 2018 (qui come titolo, non come didascalia):

[image: FrancescaPa dice "Le serate , quelle belle."]

---

### Datazione

Cercando su google «`"gli amici quelli belli" OR "i regali quelli belli" OR "le sorprese quelle belle" OR "le cene quelle belle" OR "le colazioni quelle belle" OR "i vestiti quelli belli" OR "i viaggi quelli belli" OR "le spiagge quelle belle"`» e limitando la ricerca ai risultati fino a una certa data (il filtro per data non funziona troppo bene però: bisogna controllare singolarmente i risultati) **mi sembra di non trovare riscontri antecedenti alla fine del 2016**. (Nella sua risposta @emiliano trova esempi di questa tendenza fin dal 2012)

---

#### PS

Ho oggi appreso che tali forme si chiamano "[Snowclone](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone)".

Comment: Non l'avevo mai sentita. È vero che non frequento i social network, ma è possibile che si tratti di un uso regionale?

Comment: @DenisNardin credo sia abbastanza generale. Provo ad aggiungere degli esempi più tardi

Comment: Anch'io, come @DenisNardin, non l'avevo mai sentito, e anch'io non frequento i social network. È molto interessante perché sembrerebbe – da questi scarsi elementi, che andrebbero confermati – che appartenga a una sorta di dialetto dei social network (così come ci sono quelli regionali, nonché i gerghi del giornalismo, dello sport, dell'informatica etc.).

Comment: @DaG sì è decisamente qualcosa di esclusivo dei social network. Quest'espressione, insieme a "E poi ti succede che..." (usato per introdurre brevi aneddoti), mi sembra essere un modo – pigro a dire il vero – per rendere di interesse generale un fatto privato e fondamentalmente di scarso interesse per gli altri. Insomma, invece di raccontarti la *mia* esperienza, uso delle parole riguardanti un'esperienza generica, generici regali, generiche cene.

Comment: Neanche a farlo apposta, ne ho visto per la prima volta un esempio “in natura”: mi è stata mandata un'immagine di un presepe con un crocifisso al posto del bambinello e la didascalia “Gli spoiler quelli belli”.

Comment: Sono entusiasta che qualcun altro sia interessato all'origine di quest'espressione che trovo ripugnante (per quanto perfettamente lecita)! Un'ipotesi che avevo fatto - ma senza riscontri, per il momento - è che sia la traduzione di un'espressione inglese.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Giuliano! Penso che tuo post sia più un commento che una risposta e, per questa ragione, è stato convertito.

Comment: @Giuliano: Già che siamo su un sito dedicato alla lingua italiana, si scrive “qualcun altro”, non *“qualcun'altro”.

Comment: @DaG: Ho fatto questa correzione.

Answer (score 5):

Sfida interessante, per il momento ho trovato una attestazione di aprile 2015, che sicuramente non è la prima: http://www.diarioromano.it/i-graffiti-quelli-belli-al-quadraro/

Forse occorre andare ancora più indietro:
 
13 ottobre 2014 "I giocattoli quelli belli"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcxR_xIttMI
15 ottobre 2013 "I seguiti Disney... quelli belli"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fZfw72LKxY
19 ottobre 2012 "........le amicizie..... quelle belle"
https://plus.google.com/113909773326040311517/posts/PjSrFYnbTyC
Credo che tutto parta dal ritornello del brano *Dove sono i colori* di Alessandra Amoroso, datato 2010/11
https://genius.com/Alessandra-amoroso-dove-sono-i-colori-live-lyrics

*Dove sono i colori*
*Le parole che respiri dentro le canzoni*
*Dove sono **i segreti***
***Quelli belli** che ti fanno solo immaginare*
*Non ci sei dietro l'angolo di casa ad aspettarmi*
*Fuori dal portone per parlare di tutto fino all'alba*
*Per poi fare colazione*

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Potresti includere il testo di questo brano nel tuo post?

Comment: Grazie @Emiliano di aver portato indietro la data di nascita dell'espressione! Quanto alla tua congettura sull'origine: interessante, anche se me ne devo ancora convincere

Comment: Non so, sono frasi perfettamente lecite in italiano, quindi qualche uso isolato in passato non penso sia molto rilevante, tanto più che in quella canzone è pure divisa in due versi. Ad esempio qui c'è un aforisma del 2008: https://www.pensieriparole.it/aforismi/ricordi/frase-63503

Penso che l'origine vada piuttosto cercata nel contesto social, soprattuto perché pare che l'uso sia limitato a questo ambito, come altri hanno indicato

Comment: @OldManofAran esprime bene cosa intendevo con il mio non essere convinto! Insomma, spero di trovare un inequivocabile spot pubblicitario con "I panettoni, quelli belli" (o qualcosa del genere) come slogan a sé stante, altrimenti sarò più tentato di credere a un'emergenza casuale rispetto a un'origine celebre.